# Can't get received messages

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

Somehow I see in the app messages I sent, but can't see those which should be received from others. Also when I'm sending a message it's sent to all users. Here I'm sending two classes, adapter and main chat activity. I tried using inner classes, different types of getItemViewType functions but nothing works.

MessageAdapter

```
class MessageAdapter(val context: Context, val messageList: ArrayList<Message>):
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    val ITEM_RECIEVE = 1
    val ITEM_SENT = 2

    class SentViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
    {
        val sentMessage = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt_sent_message)
    }

    class RecieveViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
    {
        val recieveMessage = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt_recieve_message)
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        val currentMessage = messageList[position]

        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid.equals(currentMessage.senderId)) {
            return ITEM_SENT
        }
        else {
            return ITEM_RECIEVE
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        if (viewType == 1)
        {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recieve, parent, false)
            Log.d("tag2", "testrecieveviewholderview11")
            return RecieveViewHolder(view)
        }
        else
        {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.sent, parent, false)
            Log.d("tag", "testsentviewholderview22")
            return SentViewHolder(view)
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val currentMessage = messageList[position]

        if(holder.javaClass == SentViewHolder::class.java)
        {
            val viewHolder = holder as SentViewHolder
            holder.sentMessage.text = currentMessage.message
        }
        else
        {
            val viewHolder = holder as RecieveViewHolder
            holder.recieveMessage.text = currentMessage.message
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return messageList.size
    }

}
```

And ChatActivity

```
    var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser? = null
    private lateinit var messageRecyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var messageBox: EditText
    private lateinit var sendButton: ImageButton
    private lateinit var messageAdapter: MessageAdapter
    private lateinit var messageList: ArrayList<Message>
    private lateinit var mRef: DatabaseReference

    var recieverRoom: String? = null
    var senderRoom: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat)

        val intent = Intent()
        val name = intent.getStringExtra("name")
        val recieverUid = intent.getStringExtra("uid")

        val senderUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
        mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

        senderRoom = recieverUid + senderUid
        recieverRoom = senderUid + recieverUid


        messageRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.RecyclerViewChat)
        messageBox = findViewById(R.id.messageBox)
        sendButton = findViewById(R.id.sendButton)

        messageList = ArrayList()
        messageAdapter = MessageAdapter(this, messageList)

        messageRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        messageRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(messageAdapter.itemCount-1)
        messageRecyclerView.adapter = messageAdapter

        mRef.child("chats").child(senderRoom!!).child("messages")
            .addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                    messageList.clear()

                    for (postSnapshot in snapshot.children)
                    {
                        val message = postSnapshot.getValue(Message::class.java)
                        messageList.add(message!!)
                    }
                    messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }

                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

                }

            })

        sendButton.setOnClickListener {
            if (messageBox.text.toString().isEmpty() || messageBox.text.toString().isBlank())
            {
                messageBox.setText("")
            }
            else {
                val message = messageBox.text.toString()
                val messageObject = Message(message, senderUid)

                mRef.child("chats").child(senderRoom!!).child("messages").push()
                    .setValue(messageObject).addOnSuccessListener {
                        mRef.child("chats").child(recieverRoom!!).child("messages").push()
                            .setValue(messageObject)
                    }
                messageBox.setText("")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: "but nothing works" but nothing works doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 0):

The error coming in this code is "Unresolved reference: message" and "Unresolved reference: senderId" in MessageAdapter. MessageAdapter is not able to take variables that are declared in Message class(message and senderId).

Comment: One of the imported files in this code is giving the error. Check for that, Hope you'll find it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is because you have imported the wrong Message class in your MessageAdapter. In your import statement, you're using android.os.Message, which is a system class and not your custom Message class. To resolve this, you need to import your custom Message class, like this:

import com.example.chatapplication.Message

Comment: Maybe a formatted text makes yours answer more easy to read :)